# how to replace special characters only at the beginning and end

Tags: php, preg-replace

i'm currently using this code to replace special characters and i was wondering if there's a way to replace only the first and last character and leave the ones in the middle.

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^ \p{L}\p{N} \@ \_ \- \.\#\$\&]/u', '', $name);
```

Thanks

Comment: Quick solution, for the start: `$name = preg_replace('/^[^ \p{L}\p{N} \@ \_ \- \.\#\$\&]/u', '', $name);` for the end `$name = preg_replace('/[^ \p{L}\p{N} \@ \_ \- \.\#\$\&]$/u', '', $name);`

Comment: Note that `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` will also remove combining diacritic characters; i.e. *accent* characters that combine with the previous letter to form an *accented* letter.

Comment: @Twisted1919, thanks a lot but it didn't work, the reply will be empty string when i use the name A&S, what i really need is to remove the & if it came in the beginning of name or at the end but keep it if it was in the middle as it will not effect the code and give an error

Comment: @arnaud576875, I'm really sorry coz i'm not a pro in PHP so i really don't know anything you said :)

Answer (score 0):

use `$name = preg_replace(array('/^[\W|\d]+/','/[\W|\d]+$/'), '', $name);` this will remove every non letter character (including accent characters) and digits from the begin and end of your string. If you want to keep the digits remove the `|\d` twice.

If you prefer Unicode Regular Expressions (read also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)
try: `$name = preg_replace(array('/^\P{L}+/u','/\P{L}+$/u'), '', $name);`

If you only have to replace a fixed set of characters like '&-_ ' you also could use `trim()`.

Comment: i really need help if there's a way to enable everything without causing reply error, what i have is a chat bot script, if a user name was starting with tag or & or ' " it will cause bot reply empty name, is there a way to fix this without replacing anything ?
thanks in advance

Comment: `$name=ltrim($name,'&\'"');` i don't know what the meaning of "tag" is?

Comment: i mean that i need to replace <>"'& if it comes at the beginning or end of name, but if there's a way to show them without causing error i would be grateful.

Comment: $name=trim($name,'&\'"<>');